# Function that hides a label depending on radio button

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm trying to get a function working that hides a label in the form depending on the radio button option selected. Here's my code so far.

> HTML

```
<form action="">
<input type="radio" id="test" value="first"> first<br>
<input type="radio" id="test" value="second"> second<br>
<input type="radio" id="test"  value="third"> third
</form>

<label class="hidden">Hide this</label>
```

> Javascript

```
var rbtn = document.getElementById("test");
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");

function hidelabel() {

  if (rbtn == 'third') {
    x.style.display='none';
}
}
```

Comment: You cannot have the same ID multiple times. `document.getElementById` only selects _one_ element.

Comment: Where you are calling `hidelabel()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must fire your hide function after radio button clicked like this:

```
document.mainForm.onclick = function(){
    var radVal = document.mainForm.rads.value;
    if (radVal == 'third') {
        document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

ps: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array. So you cannot use `x.style.display='none';`.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/5ts0dak4/

Answer (score 0):

First name the radio button ID's with something decent:

```
<form action="">
<input type="radio" id="first" value="first"> first<br>
<input type="radio" id="second" value="second"> second<br>
<input type="radio" id="third" onclick="hide();" value="third"> third
</form>

<label class="hidden" id="hidden">Hide this</label>
```

Then try this:

```
    function hide(){
    var x = document.getElementById('hidden');

    if(document.getElementById('third').checked) {
    x.style.display='none';
}
}
```

You can test it here https://jsfiddle.net/o54mzrk5/

Comment: Thank you, but I can't seem to get this code working

Comment: @greenhillsb you should have the javascript inside a <script> code </script>.

Tags are essential.
It's working on my machine

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hidden{ display:none; }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="first" onclick="func(this, true);"> first<br>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="second" onclick="func(this, true);"> second<br>
    <input type="radio" name="test"  value="third" onclick="func(this, false);"> third
</form>

<label class="hidden">Hide this</label>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    func = function(ctrl, visible) {
        if(visible)
            document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")[0].style.display='block';
        else
            document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")[0].style.display='none';
    };

</script>
```